# How can a predator defeat an alien in melee?

Tags: aliens-vs-predator-2010

Whether playing the campaign or online, I am rarely successful in fighting an alien.  My technique is pretty much button mashing in the hope I get in more blows than the enemy.

I understand that light attacks are blockable, heavy attacks are not and light attacks counter heavy attacks.  However, I just cannot seem to put that knowledge to any good use when going up against a xenomorph.

Is there some kind of method or pattern I can use to improve my chances during a fight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the campaign I can now take on groups of 6 aliens without taking any damage (even on Nightmare mode).  The general method is:

1. Get into a corner to prevent aliens lunging from the side or behind
2. Hold block to force aliens to use heavy attacks (do this as you are retreating to a corner)
3. Counter heavy attacks and failed light attacks (sometimes the alien will try a light attack when you are blocking) with a single light attack
4. Strafe a few steps after each kill to avoid acid damage

You can also use your spear or disc after the light attack counter, but relying on single light attacks in this pattern should guarantee that you never take damage.  Most of the time you can use two quick light attacks but it adds more risk if you get the timing wrong or accidentally (auto) target another alien.

When I play online I find that the same pattern applies.  Go into a fight holding the block, and use your light attack to counter the heavy attacks.  Again, you can use weapons immediately after the counter (and you may find this is needed more than in the campaign).  You can also follow up with a heavy attack or grab too, but these are risky if you cannot get the timing just right.

The main difference with online is group fights.  Aliens won't queue up and fight you one by one.  You will have to deal with them all at the same time.  Blocking and countering gets you through most of the fight, but unless you are lucky you will need to use footwork and weapons to stay alive whilst making quick kills.  If a pair of aliens manage to time a couple of lunge attacks well you will find it hard to recover.